# Replace backslash("\") with forward slash("/") in a variable in bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I want to replace backslash(`\`) with forward slash(`/`) in a variable in bash.
I tried it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
home_mf = ${home//(\)//(/)}
```

For example, I would like

```
\a\b\c -> /a/b/c
```

Comment: This belongs on UNIX.SE

Comment: @Dan, why?  This is standard Bash, and not platform-specific.

Comment: It might be more appropriate on [so], since it can be considered a programming question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The correct substitution is

```
home_mf="${home//\\//}"
```

This breaks up as follows:

- `//` replace every
- `\\` backslash
- `/` with
- `/` slash

Demonstration:

```
$ t='\a\b\c'; echo "${t//\\//}"
/a/b/c
```

---

An alternative that may be easier to read would be to quote the pattern (`'\'` rather than `\\`) and the replacement (`"/"` rather than plain `/`):

```
home_mf="${home//'\'/"/"}"
```

Comment: Nice regex break-up to a human readable sentence :) .

Answer (score 12):

This will do it:

```
home_mf=${home//\//\\} # forward to backward slash
home_mf=${home//\\//} # backward to forward slash
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat slash.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
home=/aa/bb/cc       
home_mf=${home//\//\\}
echo $home_mf
home_mf=${home_mf//\\//}
echo $home_mf
$ ./slash.sh
+ home=aa/bb/cc
+ home_mf='\aa\bb\cc'
+ echo '\aa\bb\cc'
\aa\bb\cc
+ home_mf=/aa/bb/cc
+ echo /aa/bb/cc
/aa/bb/cc
```

The `${variable/..}` syntax is `ksh`, `bash`, and possibly other shells specific but is not be present in all Bourne shell syntax based shells, e.g. `dash`. Should you want a portable way (POSIX), you might use `sed` instead:

```
home_mf=$(printf "%s" "$home" | sed 's/\//\\/g')    # forward to backward slash
home_mf=$(printf "%s" "$home_mf" | sed 's/\\/\//g') # backward to forward slash
```

Comment: doesn't work echo "output: $home_mf" returns "output: homeuser" for "/home/user"

Comment: Answer edited to demonstrate it works with me. Not sure what happens in your case, try using `printf "%s\n" "$home_mf"` instead of `echo "$home_mf"`.

Comment: Might be an idea to use a different character as separator in the sed `s` command, e.g. `s,/,\\,g` and `s,\\,/,g`.